# Filter columns in Google Spreadsheets based on fill colour

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a long list of items that I need to check. I use a traffic light system to track where I change the cell colour of the cells in the progress column:

- red = haven't done
- yellow = in progress
- green = done

Is there a way in Google Drive Spreadsheets to filter my progress column by cell fill?

Answer (score 4):

I would put the progress-value into a column, and then use conditional formatting based on that to set the cell background.    And then you can filter on the progress column directly.

(I've never liked the idea of just colouring cells and then trying to extract the value of them:  in principle, if you want to record some data then do it directly.)